# Opening With a Video In The iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

How would I go about starting my application with a video like Gameloft does with their opening video?

Comment: Would the easiest way to do this be play the video with ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

You could call it in `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` and then use `- (void) moviePreloadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification` to do something when it finishes playing.